# What determines output voltage in a feedforward DC/DC converter?

Tags: power, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I am designing system that includes a solar power stage with an MPP tracker. The DC/DC converter in the MPPT is feedforward, i.e. it regulates the input voltage of the solar panel to the maximum power point. However, the output is then left unregulated. *Note: it will not be connected to a battery directly like it is often done*, it will be a separate "MPPT bus" from which various loads will draw.

In such a configuration, what would determine the output voltage of the converter? Is it the load, or do component values play a role as well? Or is the duty cycle still defining the input/output voltage relationship?

I am using a buck/boost converter, but you can assume any non-isolated topology, I am looking to understand the principle.

Comment: *what would determine the output voltage of the converter?* - totally, the schematic and the parts list and any loads connected to it plus details of the solar panels. Basically everything you haven't disclosed.

Comment: It's everything - what happens if there is no load and you try to regulate in such a way that the MPP is met? Where will the power go - will the voltage be regulated up to infinity to finally get an arc to get some current going? What happens if you have a higher load than you can supply?

Answer (score 0):

You really want to hook that converter to a battery. MPP converts generally assume they are charging a big battery that can take more current than the converter will ever put out.  Any good design will have a maximum output voltage limit above which they stop trying to be MPP.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, I have a battery in my system that I will use in this fashion. I was just curious what else, besides loads, will influence the output voltage.